# Error : babelHelpers is not defined. using JSPM bundle

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, systemjs, jspm

I wrote a JavaScript app using ES6. While this works fine when I run `npm run serve`, now I'm trying to prepare the files for production and upload to server.

When I tried `jspm bundle` and uploading to the server it failes on

> babelHelpers is not defined

To my understanding this looks like transpilation is trying to run on runtime and then missing something.

1. If possible, I would like to transpile and then bundle the files
2. If not, how do I solve this babelHelper issue.

For now in my `config.js` only the transpiler is defined (babel). Perhaps I need to config it better using babelOption or other?

Comment: The wording of your question is understandable, but the lack of formatting makes it hard to read. This site has *great* Markdown support, so consider reading [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and editing your question so it's easier to read. I'd recommend formatting any commands you include (e.g., `npm run serve`  or `jspm bundle ...`) so that it's obvious that these are things you explicitly typed into a terminal. Same for error messages (`babelHelpers is not defined`). You'll get more answers if you take the time to make your post beautiful, and this site makes that easy.

Comment: I added some basic formatting to your question so it's easier to read. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time.